# Priority Encoder with Memory

Tags: digital-logic, sequential-logic

I am looking for some kind of pin channel selector design for 16 signals, 0-5V. When a specific signal got high, I should get its number (address) over a 4 pins address. No simultaneous highs will occur.

I made an over simplification with 3 signals, and 2 address pins in the attached figure. I put three signals, and with the positive edge, I should recover the corresponding address -i.e. if the pin is the IN01, I should be able to get the "01" address through the OUT00 and OUT01 pins, and feed this into a uP for taking actions.

I could figure using RS latches for recovering the OUT00, but this procedure (could?) not be extensible at all for more signals and address pins. And surely with a single microprocessor accepting positive edging logic i could solve that straightfordwardly, but perhaps a uP could be too much for this.

Should I follow some Flip-Flop solution, or should discard them and seek for some digital programmable device?

[image]

Edit: The key functionality is called *Priority Encoder*, which can be implemented with a 74HC148, a delay line 2 Schmitt Trigger with \$R=10k\Omega\$, \$C=1uF\$, an additional Schmitt Trigger used as inverter, and an Universal Register 74HC194 used in parallel mode.

Comment: Check the 74xx TTL databook for `Priority Encoder`. This can be implemented in combinational logic, does not require any clock or flip-flops.

Comment: Figure 2. Priority Encoder for 16 Bits http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc148.pdf

Comment: Your timing diagram shows *memory*, so yes, you do need some sort of flip-flop. A priority encoder is only part of the solution. Actually, a simple encoder would do since you already know that simultaneous inputs will not occur.

Comment: It is right, I checked the Priority Encoder and the cascading feature, and now i am figuring a digital delay with a [Schmitt Trigger + RC Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349453/how-to-introduce-delay-to-a-signal) for using the GS signal from the Priority Encoder as a clock into some kind of register...

Comment: Thanks to all... I finally calculated this using a 74HC148, a delay line with 3 Schmitt Triggers 74HC14 with RC=10k,1uF and an 74HC194.